# Interpreting / Testing strings in ANTLRWorks 2

Tags: string, migration, interpreter, antlrworks, antlrworks2

ANTLRWorks 1.5 has an "Interpreter" tab where you could enter strings to test your parser on. So far I haven't been able to find anything equivalent in ANTLRWorks 2. Does it have anything like that, and if so, how is it accessed?

Answer (score 3):

I have been looking for that feature as well.

The only way I have found is the menu `Run > Run in TestRig...`. Unfortunately the input has to be provided in a file.

[image: TestRig]